# Проблема создание компонента интерфейса treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Хочу винести в одельный компонет(UserControl) **TreeView** для использование его.
Проблемма с биндингом не отображаються данные из коллекции **Сar**.

**TreeViewFlex**-компонент

```
public partial class TreeViewFlex : UserControl
{
  
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceRootProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ItemsSourceRoot), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(TreeViewFlex),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ItemsSourceRootProperty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSourceRoot
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceRootProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceRootProperty, value); }
    }

    public TreeViewFlex()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```xml
<TreeView  
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle_ExpandAll}"                           
        
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceRoot}"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
            <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviours:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </e:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Width="20" Height="20"  Source="{Binding Icon}"   />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Caption}"  />
                    </Grid>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**Как это использую**

```xml
<Components:TreeViewFlex Grid.Row="3" ItemsSourceRoot="{Binding Car, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0"/>
```

Comment: переименовать `ItemsSourceProperty` => `ItemsSourceRootProperty`

Comment: @aepot результат тотже.

Comment: Исправьте тогда код в вопросе в соответствии с моим предложением потому что сейчас ItemsSourceProperty конфликтует с таким же DP у TreeView.

Comment: `TreeViewFlex : UserControl` вам не кажется, что надо делать `TreeViewFlex : TreeView` в таком случае?

Comment: @aepot Как понял,вы предлагаете написать свой элемент управления унаследовая функции TreeView?

Comment: Да, именно так. Но я пока не до конца понял смысл задачи, поэтому могу ошибаться.

Comment: @aepot У меня есть 3 TreeView,хочу вынести  TreeView в одельный код(UserControl) который буду использовать. Может у меня будет 5 TreeView они очень грамоздкие. Моя  идея разобрать ui на части.

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceRoot}"` DataContext должен указывать на экземпляр `TreeViewFlex`, скорее всего у вас он не такой. Попробуйте `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceRoot, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"` или `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`

Comment: Так для этого не надо создаваю юзерконтролы, можно вынести только `<TreeView.ItemTemplate>` в отдельный `<Style>`, вообще все это описать можно с помощью Style.

Comment: @aepot  Cпасибо заработало `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceRoot, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Comment: Лучшое решение написать свой контроллер,но пока оставлю так. Потому что данную  тему надо изучить.

Comment: @aepot Еще один вопрос как можно сделать зависимость свойств если оно статикечкое?

Comment: Свойства не должны быть статическими, [но возможно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936331/12888024), да. В любом случае, я не рекомендую использовать статику в привязках, она вам много граблей подложит в будущем.

Comment: @Спасибо за   информацию,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<UserControl x:Class="LogicTrain.Components.TreeViewFlex"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogicTrain.Components"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
            
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:LogicTrain.Common"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LogicTrain.ViewModels"
             xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
             xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
             xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:LogicTrain.Behaviors"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle_ExpandAll" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <TreeView  
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle_ExpandAll}"                           
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceRoot, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
            <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviours:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </e:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Width="20" Height="20"  Source="{Binding Icon}"   />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Caption}"  />
                    </Grid>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```